# Python - collections.OrderedDict() is not ordering dictionary properly

Tags: python, string, sorting, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have a list of dictionary as follows:

```
[{'17': 1}, {'17': 1, '19': 1}, {'8': 1, '9': 2, '12': 3}, {'23': 3}]
```

I want to merge the dictionaries in the list which I do by:

```
    from collections import Counter

    c = Counter()
    for d in hourofDayData:
        c.update(d)
    temp = dict(c)
```

for which I get the following output:

```
{'17': 2, '19': 1, '8': 1, '9': 2, '12': 3, '23': 3}
```

which is what I want, except that it is not ordered. I want the above dictionary to be like:

```
{'8': 1, '9': 2, '12': 3,'17': 2, '19': 1,  '23': 3}
```

I tried to use collections.OrderedDict like this:

```
OrderedDict([('12', 3), ('17', 2), ('19', 1), ('23', 3), ('8', 1), ('9', 2)])
```

Again, which is not ordered. How do I make the dictionary ordered?

Comment: You want a **sorted** dictionary, not just any plain old **ordered** dictionary.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, how can I get sorted dictionary?

Comment: `OrderedDict` keeps track of the order the keys/values are inserted. It does *not* sort by the keys (or values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points to note:

1. `OrderedDict` is insertion ordered, not ordered by size.
2. Your keys are strings. For ordering by integer size, you need to convert them to integers.

Considering these aspects, you can use `sorted` with a custom `key` defined to construct a list of tuples. Then feed this ordered collection to `OrderedDict`:

```
d = {'17': 2, '19': 1, '8': 1, '9': 2, '12': 3, '23': 3}

from collections import OrderedDict

res = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0])))
```

Result:

```
OrderedDict([('8', 1), ('9', 2), ('12', 3), ('17', 2), ('19', 1), ('23', 3)])
```

It is worth noting in Python 3.7 dictionaries are insertion ordered and this fact can be relied upon. In this case, `OrderedDict` can be replaced by `dict` provided the additional methods of `OrderedDict` are not required.

Answer (score 0):

You should sort the dictionary first then you should convert it to ordereddict.  Check the following code.

```
import collections
from collections import Counter

hourofDayData = [{'17': 1}, {'17': 1, '19': 1}, {'8': 1, '9': 2, '12': 3}, {'23': 3}]

c = Counter()
for d in hourofDayData:
    c.update(d)
temp = dict(c)
def get_key(key):
    try:
        return int(key)
    except ValueError:
        return key
print(collections.OrderedDict(sorted(temp.items(), key=lambda t: get_key(t[0]))))
```

Prints:

```
OrderedDict([('8', 1), ('9', 2), ('12', 3), ('17', 2), ('19', 1), ('23', 3)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
times=[{'17': 1}, {'17': 1, '19': 1}, {'8': 1, '9': 2, '12': 3}, {'23': 3}]
```

You can do:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

cnt={}
for d in times:
    for k, v in d.items():
        cnt[k]=cnt.get(k, 0)+v

>>> OrderedDict(sorted([(k,v) for k,v in cnt.items()], key=lambda t:int(t[0])))
OrderedDict([('8', 1), ('9', 2), ('12', 3), ('17', 2), ('19', 1), ('23', 3)])
```

With Python 3.6+, you do not need to use `OrderedDict` since the keys of a regular `dict` use insertion order.

Python 3.7:

```
cnt={}
for d in times:
    for k, v in d.items():
        cnt[k]=cnt.get(k, 0)+v

>>> dict(sorted([(k,v) for k,v in cnt.items()], key=lambda t:int(t[0])))  
{'8': 1, '9': 2, '12': 3, '17': 2, '19': 1, '23': 3}
```